# How would I combine two async libraries?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How would I go about combining two asyncio libraries in the same program?

For context,  I wish to use the [Discord api](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) with aiohttp, both of which are async event loop driven. I may potentially want to add an async irc library to the mix, too.

However, I don't understand how they would be operated together. I believe that in theory I would implement the program such that all class instances utilise the same asyncio event loop instance, and then kludge all the run functions together into one, ultimately calling the event loop.

However, I would like to know if there is in general a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: It depends on which libraries your are using exactly due to compatibility of event loops

Comment: Well then, considering the three: aiohttp, the discord api linked above, and possibly https://github.com/gawel/irc? Though to be honest, I was hoping that there would be some general, elegant way of doing so.

Comment: i think you're on the right track. you should be able to just set the same event loop for all, but it's not a kludge to have coroutines from different libraries managed from the same event loop.

Comment: Sometimes you can run the event loops in parallel on different threads. The trick then is to figure out how to pass messages among them.

Comment: @Acushner Well, that's fair, but each library tends to implement their own `run` function which does some preparatory work. So I'm going to have to kludge *those* together.

Comment: @Firnagzen Just came across your question while looking to do much the same thing. Did you find a nice solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, not particularly - I wound up using a common event loop, and then modifying their individual run functions together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all the libraries use the same eventloop they will work together nicely. In this case it seems like all the libraries you choosed are based on asyncio (excetp gawel's IRC lib which is not available anymore). So there is no problem. There is a single eventloop (and no threads) and all is well.

The problem you face is that you will have several "servers" in the same event loop or more accuratly there is several coroutines that handle input from the outside world. One coroutine is handling the HTTP traffic and the other is handling the IRC "traffic". In pseudo-code, it can be translated to the following:

```
import asyncio



async def irc_server():
    async with irc_connect('irc.freenode.net#python-fr') as irc:
        async for message in irc:
            # do something useful with message

async def web_server():
    async with web_connect('localhost:8080') as web:
        async for request in web:
            # do something useful with request


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(irc_server())
loop.create_task(web_server())

loop.run_forever()
```

As such, both coroutines have no way to communicate. To make the HTTP part communicate with the IRC part you have to share something between the two coroutines. In production it's prolly somekind of database but in pseudo code, it's a simple global. You will end up with something like that:

```
import asyncio


# value is shared between IRC and the web server.
value = None



async def irc_server():
    global value
    async with irc_connect('irc.freenode.net#python-fr') as irc:
        async for message in irc:
            # if message is echo, reply with the current value
            # otherwise store the message as value
            if message == 'echo':
                irc.send(value)
            else:
                value = message

async def web_server():
    global value
    async with web_connect('localhost:8080') as web:
        async for request in web:
            if request.path == 'echo':
                request.client.send(value)
            else:
                value = request.path  # this is silly but simple


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(irc_server())
loop.create_task(web_server())

loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: is it fine to use `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator on an `async def` or is it just a bug in the above code?

Comment: it was bug, sorry.